# Fill $N$ by $M$ grid with numbers in such a way that any given cells' neighbors are different

Tags: geometry, optimization, grid-deduction, algorithm

Create an $N$ by $M$ grid with numbers in such a way that satisfies following conditions:

1. numbers should be integers that range from $1$ to $r$.
2. for any cell $C$, all its adjacent neighbors (i.e. bottom, top, left, right cells) must have different values.
3. $r$ must be minimal.

For example, a solution for a $3$ by $3$ grid is...

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 2\\1 & 3 & 4\\2 & 3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

In this case, $r = 4$.

Comment: The worst case is 4 since this is just a special case of the map coloring problem

Comment: @DrXorile I disagree. I think the graph corresponding to this problem is not planar when $N,M$ are large enough ($N=M=4$?), which is one of the prerequisites for the four-colour theorem to apply. The worst case may be $4$ nevertheless, but not because of that.

Comment: @Jaap, I cannot see how a 2d matrix could be anything but planar

Comment: @DrXorile I'm with Jaap on this, I don't see the connection. For instance, you can change the problem from "square" cells to hexagonal ones where each hexagon has to border six, each containing different numbers. How would the analogue generalise?

Comment: Took me a bit but I think this is more of a variant than a special case of the map coloring problem.

Comment: FYI @Hugh, the possessive form of "its" [does not have an apostrophe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/its).

Comment: @DrXorile On a normal map in the 4-colour theorem, countries that touch only at a single point are not considered adjacent, because otherwise you could let 100 countries meet and you'd need 100 colours. Consider the four neighbours of a cell. These are supposed to be pairwise adjacent, because they all need to get different colours/numbers. On a normal map, you can make the top and bottom regions adjacent by putting a border line between them, but that cuts the left/right regions off from each other. But here the top/bottom adjacency crosses over the left/right - i.e. non-planar.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. My bad

Comment: @tilper oh, I'm sorry. I was typing pretty carelessly and I must have missed it when I was proofreading. Sorry!

Comment: @Hugh, no problem at all!  I see from your history you like to make grammar edits whenever possible, which is great, so just wanted to make sure.  Keep it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose that

> **1.** If $\min(N,M) \geq 3$ then $r=4$ 
>  **2.** If $\min(N,M) = 2$ and $\max(N,M) > 2$ then $r=3$ 
>  **3.** If $M=N=2$ then $r=2$ 
>  **4.** If $\min(N,M) = 1$ and $\max(N,M) > 2$ then $r=2$ 
>  **5.** If $\min(N,M) = 1$ and $\max(N,M) \leq 2$  then $r=1$

Proof

 **1.**

> If $\min(N,M) \geq 3$ then there is at least one cell surrounded by $4$ others and all have different values. Hence, $r \geq 4$. 
>  Now suppose we colour the cells of the grid like a chessboard and do the following: 
>  (i) In every odd-numbered column number the white squares $1$ and $2$ alternately, always beginning each column with the opposite number of the previous, as shown [image] 
> (ii) Proceed analogously for the white squares in the even-numbered columns and the numbers $3$ and $4$, as shown [image] 
> (iii) Now do exactly the same for the black squares and we are done [image] 
>  Hence we can always achieve $r \leq 4$ and in this scenario we have $r=4$

**2.**

> If $\min(N,M) = 2$ but $\max(N,M) >2$, then we know there is at least one cell with $3$ neighbours. Hence, $r \geq 3$.
>  Without loss of generality suppose $N=2$ (i.e, $2$ rows but more than $2$ columns) then we can fill each row with the repeating sequence $1,2,3,1,2,3,\ldots$. That is, we have $$\left(\begin{array}{l}1&2&3&1&2&3&\ldots\\1&2&3&1&2&3&\ldots\end{array}\right) $$ That is, we have $r \leq 3$. 
>  Hence, $r=3$ in this case.

**3.**

> If $N=M=2$ then we know that $r \geq 2$ since each cell has $2$ neighbours.
>  To achieve $r=2$, we can put $1$s in the first column and $2$s in the second as shown  $$\left(\begin{array}{l}1&2\\1&2\end{array}\right) $$

**4.**

> If $\min(N,M) =1$ and $\max(N,M) > 2$ then there is at least one cell with $2$ neighbours so $r \geq 2$. 
>  To achieve $r=2$, we can fill the single row (or column) with a repeating sequence $$ \left( 1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,\ldots \right) $$

**5.**

> There are just two cases here, really, and, in both, we can fill the grid with $1$s that is, $$ (1) \,\,\,\,\text{  and  } \,\,\,\,(1 1) $$

Answer (score 2):

> The answer is always r = 4 in cases where m and n are greater than 2.
>
>  [image]
>
>  This pattern can be repeated across the grid and cut off at the edges. In the cases where m and n are greater than 2, there will be a 3x3 grid where, you have already said r = 4. When one of m or n is 2 and the other is greater, r = 3 because you can repeat [1,1] [2,2] and [3,3] but you need 3 because there will be a square with 3 around it. The pattern for a 1xm grid is 1,1,2,2,1,1 etc. In a 2x2 however the answer is r = 2 and in a 1x1 or 1x2 the answers are r = 1. These are fairly easy to see/test.

Comment: This is incorrect. A cell cannot have neighbors that are identical to itself.

Comment: I don’t think that is specified in the question and the example has a cell with a neighbour which is identical.

Comment: The example may be wrong. The question says, under rule 2: **for any cell C, all its' adjacent neighbors [i.e. bottom, top, left, right cells] must have different values**

Comment: I think the wording is ambiguous but the example would suggest that the cell itself is not included in its adjacent cells

Comment: **Edit** oh, sorry. I've been reading it wrong. Please ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

If all cells including itself must be different:

> r=5, as this pattern tessellates:
>
> ```
>  A B C D E
>  D E A B C
>  B C D E A
>  E A B C D
>  C D E A B
> ```